# Convert array of string into array of object with different keys JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of string, which I want to map into an array of objects with different keys. The keys are set before hand, but the amount of string can differ.

So I have an array of strings like this:

```
let obj =[
    '612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c',
    '15',
    '15',
    'Basketball',
    '2021'
]
```

And I need to map them into an array of objects with the following keys:

```
let arrayOfObejcts = [{ id: '', amount: '', bet: '', sport: '', date: ''}]
```

So far this is what I got:

```
const mappedArr = obj.map(value => {
    return {
        name: value, amount: value, bet: value, sport: value, date: value
    }
})
console.log(mappedArr)
```

Unfortunatly, this just gives med an array of objects with the correct keys, but the same value in all of them. The result I want would look like this:

```
let result= [{ id: '612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c', amount: '15', bet: '15', sport: 'Basketball', date: '2021'}]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm still kinda new to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one array containing one set of data there's no need to use `map`. [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the array elements, and then just create a new object using those variables.

```js
const arr = [ '612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c', '15', '15', 'Basketball', '2021' ];

const [ id, amount, bet, sport, date ] = arr;
const obj = [ { id, amount, bet, sport, date } ];
console.log(obj);
```

If you *do* have an array of nested arrays containing those strings, `map` is handy, but the same technique applies.

```js
const arr = [ ['612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c', '15', '15', 'Basketball', '2021' ], [ '4354354', '20', '10', 'Soccer', '2020' ] ];

const result = arr.map(nested => {
  const [ id, amount, bet, sport, date ] = nested;
  return { id, amount, bet, sport, date };
});

console.log(result);
```

Final approach. If you have just *one* array containing *all* of your data just use a simple loop that slices off five elements at a time and creates an object from them. You can then push those into a new array.

```js
const arr = [ '612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c', '15', '15', 'Basketball', '2021', '4354354', '20', '10', 'Soccer', '2020' ];

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 5) {
  const nested = arr.slice(i, i + 5);
  const [ id, amount, bet, sport, date ] = nested;
  result.push({ id, amount, bet, sport, date });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This approch however dont work if the array of strings have two sets of data. e.g: 

let arr =[
    '612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c',
    '15',
    '15',
    'Basketball',
    '2021',
    '6128907101e3f400042f9e11',
    '16',
    '15',
    'Baseball',
    '2021'
].

Comment: So is it just one array containing the data for multiple objects?

Comment: It is not an array of nested arrays. It is still simply one  array with multiple strings for multiple objects yes.

Comment: I updated my answer to take account of that @egx.

Comment: you are the man! Thank you so much for all the examples. This is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You could take another array for the keys and map indexvise all entries and build an object from it.

```js
const
    data =['612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c', '15', '15', 'Basketball', '2021'],
    keys = ['id', 'amount', 'bet', 'sport', 'date'],
    result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, data[i]]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Like the answer below this will not work if the data array has to sets of data. e.g. : let obj =[
    '612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c',
    '15',
    '15',
    'Basketball',
    '2021',
    '6128907101e3f400042f9e11',
    '16',
    '15',
    'Baseball',
    '2021'
]

Here I would want to result to be an array containing two of the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are converting array of strings to a single object. Just create it with

```
let result = [{
  id: obj[0],
  amount: obj[1],
  ...etc
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructuration is what you need.

Note that it'd work only if you key order never changes.

```js
const obj =[
    '612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c',
    '15',
    '15',
    'Basketball',
    '2021'
];
const [ name, amount, bet, sport, date ] = obj;
const result = [{ name, amount, bet, sport, date }]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this approch, like the answer above, dont work if the array contains strings representing multiple objects. Like this: 

let obj =[
    '612772d3d8b2b2000482fc3c',
    '15',
    '15',
    'Basketball',
    '2021',
    '6128907101e3f400042f9e11',
    '16',
    '15',
    'Baseball',
    '2021'
]

Comment: @egx you should update what you're looking for, as it drastically changes the answer.